# Cronjob - run job at 8:00 pm and then after every 12 hrs

Tags: mysql, cron

I am running a backup database cronjob in the MySQL server. and I am trying to run a backup cronjob to take one backup at 8:00 AM and then another at 8 PM.

Please help me with this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
0 8-20/12 * * * /usr/bin/true
```

or probably more readable

```
0 8,20 * * * /usr/bin/true
```

Please read `man 5 crontab`.